# ReferenceError: Method is not defined (Mockup js)

Tags: javascript

I would like to `fetchDriver()` every few minutes, but I am unable to call `fetchDriver()` out side the `initMap()`.

`fetchDriver()` calls on my api and drops a marker on the map to provide the "drivers" location.

I need to call  fetchDriver from outside the initmap so the map remains static for the mos part.

Thanks for any help on this issue.

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px" class="img-thumbnail"></div>

<script>
  var map;

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 0000, lng: 0000},
      zoom: 10,
      minZoom: 10,
      maxZoom: 15,
      scrollwheel: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      mapTypeControl: false
    });

    function fetchDriver() {
      $.get('api call', function (responseText) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(responseText);
        var location = {lat: parseFloat(obj.latitude), lng: parseFloat(obj.longitude)};
        addMarker(location);
      });
    }

    function addMarker(location) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
      });
    }
  }
</script>

<script>
  fetchDriver();
</script>


<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKeycallback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: `$` is usually a reference to `jQuery`. Are you including the `jQuery` library anywhere in your source? Also, I presume the `api call` mention is just a placeholder for an actual path?

Comment: May be @ __`$.get`__

Comment: yes the "api call" is a placeholder for an actual path.

Comment: Any reason that you can't move `fetchDriver()` and `addMarker()` functions outside of `initMap()`? Those two functions only exist in the scope of `initMap()` so if you're trying to recall that function in the global scope, you're going to get that error and it doesn't even look like you're calling those functions within `initMap()`.

Comment: Correct, I need to call them outside the `initMap()` function.